# Triangle Congruency

Tags: geometry

I believe that the following statement, $\triangle ONR $ is congruent to $\triangle ARN $, cannot be proven by any of the normal congruency postulates. Is this the case?

[image]

Comment: Why do you believe so?

Comment: You are correct.  If ON is parallel to AR, or OR to NA, or if NA =OR, etc, then you could conclude the triangles are congruent, but as is, you don't have enough information.

Comment: If angle A and O, are acute there are 2 ways RN can intersect AN.  It's hard to describe but what you have in essence, angle side side.  It'It's a bit more constrained as it must make a quadralateral.  But it's possible to make a non parallelogram with all those conditions but not congruent tringles.

Comment: Let angle A and O be 80, and RNA be 60, but ORN be 120, such a figure should be possible, I think.

Answer (score 0):

Observe that IF $ORNA$ a parallelogram then you can see $\overline{ON}$ as a transversal between two parallel lines. Hence $m\angle ONR=m\angle NRA$. Therefore, both triangles are congruent thanks to the S.A.S criteria (notice that obviously $\overline{RN}$ is a common side of both triangles).

Comment: ORNA doesn't have to be a parallelogram so far as I can tell.

Comment: You’re right, I didn’t express myself clearly.

Answer (score 0):

Angle-side-side is not a valid congruence theorem.

It's possible to create two triangles with angle A, and sides r, s, one with angles B and 180-A-B.  Another with angles 180-B  and B-A (assuming A < B < 90 < 180- B and the side r > s).  Construct two such non-congruent triangles, an "glue" them together on side s.

You'll have a figure that satisfies all conditions.

Comment: My geometry teacher used to say if you try to prove congruence with Angle-Side-Side you make an A-S-S of yourself.